# How to Instantiate @configuration bean based on property value from properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have two classes/beans annotated with `@Configuration` and I have to instantiate
based on the value from the property file.

#### RemoteServer1.java

```
@Configuration
public class RemoteServer1 {
    //some authentication logic goes here
}
```

#### RemoteServer2.java

```
@Configuration
public class RemoteServer2 {
    //some authentication logic goes here
}
```

#### application.properties

```
remote.server.location=RemoteServer1
```

Now i want to instantiate `@Configuration` class/bean matched with value from property file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest you look into the `@Contidional...` annotations in Spring Boot to conditionally activate Beans, Configurations etc.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html

This *should* work looking at the property and config. For the first configuration,

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="remote.server.location", havingValue="RemoteServer1",  matchIfMissing=false)
```

Second,

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="remote.server.location", havingValue="RemoteServer2",  matchIfMissing=false)
```

Looks for the property `name`, matches on `havingValue`, will not evaluate to `true` if the property is missing.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make a reference to a property file, use "${}" syntax. For example,

```
@Value("${some.prop}")
private String remoteServer
```

It will pull the value and auto-configure it to the String